# CheckMarx - How to fix the Code Injection report?

Tags: java, spring-boot, code-injection, checkmarx

Checkmarx encountered the following error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RequestMappings.PROVA, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<? extends Object> provaAction(@RequestBody(required = false) Object[] inputExample,
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
```

Error:

The application's getOutput method receives and dynamically executes usercontrolled
code using invoke, at line 153 of
Service.java. This could enable an attacker to
inject and run arbitrary code.
The attacker can inject the executed code via user input, inputExample, which is retrieved by the
application in the provaAction method, at line 39 of Service.java.

Using a method inputExample fromString, but is not function

public enum InvokeableClasses {
inputExample (InputExample .class);

```
private final Class clazz;
InvokeableClasses(Class clazz){
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public Class getClazz() {
    return this.clazz;
}

public static InvokeableClasses fromString(String className) {
    for(InvokeableClasses currentInvokeableClass : InvokeableClasses.values()) {
        if(currentInvokeableClass.getClazz().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(className)) {
            return currentInvokeableClass;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**How can I fix the checkmarx ??**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Object's built-in getClass() method instead of getClazz()

```
for(InvokeableClasses currentInvokeableClass : InvokeableClasses.values()) {
    if(currentInvokeableClass.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(className)) {
        return currentInvokeableClass;
    }
}
```

This is the method that Checkmarx recognizes